# Should I Use a diode for this application?

Tags: diodes, 12v

I am trying to run a small 12v motor from the same battery. One source is a timer the other a remote. The timer does not function when both are hooked up to the motor. I’m assuming it is from feedback. I ordered some diodes but have not been able to get them to work.

15amp Diode Axial Schottky Blocking Diodes for Solar Cells Panel

They leak current back to the timer making it malfunction. 
What do I need to do to make my set up work?

Comment: what is `same battery` ?

Comment: Diagram? Schematic?

Comment: You'll need to give us more information. We don't know what you mean by running a small motor from the "same" battery. Consider re-writing, understanding that we have no idea what your circuit looks like, and by all means do include a diagram with labels showing the parts as thay are now connected, and where you are thinking of adding these diodes.

Comment: Ok. I have 1 motor and 1 12v 7amp battery. I have an automatic timer as one of the inputs to the motor. I also have a remote control relay that also is an input to the same motor. Both get the power from the same battery. The output to the motor from both the timer and the remote have to be tied intogether. The problem in doing so is the timer is getting backfeed and messing it up. My thought was to insert a diode into the positive side of the output of the timer before it ties into the remote output. Allowing current to only go out and not back feed into the timer. What did I do wrong?

Comment: this is a guess based on insufficient information: use thicker wires to carry the current from the battery through the switches to the motor. use separate wires connect the battery power to the timer and to the remote receiver.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is no isolation at the timer output. Have the timer actuate a relay and the relay actuate the motor. Then the timer would have a "dry contacts" output. Or you could put the isolation relay at the output of the remote circuit. Either way, you prevent multiple inputs from "talking to each other" when they share a common power supply.
Relays make wonderful logic switches. On the input side you can switch the power, or you can use ground-side control. And the output can have a myriad of contact layouts including self-latching.
Try to put a fuse (maybe 10 Amp) at the positive terminal. Those 12v7Ah batteries can burn and melt things. Good luck!